# Adding g:select tag through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I'm trying to add g:select tags dynamically through a jquery function I have written. I know the function works as I use it elsewhere in the project to add a normal html element. The variable im trying to add is

```
                 var row ='<tr class="prop"> <td valign="top" style="text-alight:left;" width="20%"> <label for="batsmanHome' + rowNum + '"> Batsman: </label> </td> <td valign="top" style="text-alight:left;" width="20%"> <g:select name="batsmanHome"' + rowNum + '" from="${fixtureInView.homeTeam.players.asList()}" optionKey="id"/> </td> <td valign="top" style="text-align:left;" width="20%"> <input onclick="addRowHome(this.form);" type="button" value="Add Player" /> </td></tr>'
```

This comes up wit the error `illegal colon after argument expression;
   solution: a complex label expression before a colon must be parenthesized @ line 20, column 116.
   Home" },'' + rowNum + '" from':evaluate(
                                 ^` which I can't get my head around. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`<g:select` needs to be processed on the server side before it is converted to a regular `select` tag that the browser and front end languages like javascript can understand and manipulate.

You should change your code to:

```
                 var row ='<tr class="prop"> <td valign="top" style="text-alight:left;" width="20%"> <label for="batsmanHome' + rowNum + '"> Batsman: </label> </td> <td valign="top" style="text-alight:left;" width="20%"> <select name="batsmanHome"' + rowNum + '"  ></select> </td> <td valign="top" style="text-align:left;" width="20%"> <input onclick="addRowHome(this.form);" type="button" value="Add Player" /> </td></tr>'
```

Comment: doesn't grails tags get turned into normal html tags when show anyway? Whenever I view the source of a gsp file in a browser, it changes g:select into select.

Comment: @AdamCarlin Yes grails does that but your `<g:select` is inside a javascript string so is ignored by the grails library that expands the gsp tags.

Comment: Would this still be so if it was in a g:javascript tag?

Comment: @AdamCarlin any gsp tag inside a sting is not expanded because how can the application tell whether you intended the sting to just contain `<g:javascript` or be expanded to a script tag? Please don't hesitate to inquire more if what I'm saying is not yet clear.

Comment: I think I understand. Im guessing the easiest way to pass a g:select tag through to a script is by passing it through the controller in a string? Would this be a safe way to do it?

Comment: @AdamCarlin no, if you insist on having the `<g:select` you should put in a template and make an ajax call to a controller that renders the template. But I don't think that is what you're after.